# Pass integer to thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am (very) very new to Java. The code in question is spawning a thread that performs some action at a specific time. This time is obtained from the main thread that receives it via `http://ip:80/time=(int,sec)`

Users can call this URL and update this time as many times as they want. This means I have to pass my integer to the thread so that it can run using a given time, such as when it changes. How do I do that?

Here's how my thread is defined and launched:

```
Thread launchLoadBalancer = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(serverSocket, //object for extra data);
        try {
            timerTask.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
};
launchtimerTask.start();
```

I have to pass integer from the `new TimerTask`. I can modify the constructor on the other end. How do I correctly pass integer?

Comment: I removed the references to passing by reference.  Java does not have pass-by-reference.  It passes references by value.  The distinction is important but not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int length = 1000;
        Thread launchLoadBalancer = () -> {
            TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(serverSocket, length);
            try {
                timerTask.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
        };
        launchLoadBalancer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it would, but I don't recommend it, as complications can arise.  Instead, make an actual subclass of `Thread` with a constructor that accepts an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class that extends `Thread` and has a constructor that takes an `int`.

```
class LaunchLoadBalancerThread extends Thread {
    private int i;
    public LaunchLoadBalancerThread(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
    public void run() {
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(serverSocket, //object for extra data);
        try {
            timerTask.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use that class (replace i with your number):

```
Thread launchLoadBalancer = new LaunchLoadBalancerThread(i);
launchLoadBalancer.start();
```